# Remplazar ciertos caracteres en string, javascript o jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen dia a todos, tengo el siguiente string:

```
<div id="div_Ejem" class="ve" > <div style="width: 30px; height: 30px; z-index : 150; position: absolute; "><img src="icon.Gif" width="30" height="30" title="Assistance" alt="" style="cursor: pointer; " > </div> <div id="imgUser"><img id="img_9905" src="/folder1/folder2/NumeroImgen.jpg" /></div><span class="dataUser">INACTIVE <br /></span></div>
```

Lo que deseo es poder sustituir en algun momento esta ruta: /folder1/folder2/NumeroImgen.jpg
Pero solo quiero cambiar el dato "NumeroImgen", pueden ayudarme sobre como encontrar este dato y reemplazarlo? con jquery o javascript.

Comment: ¿Sólo `NumeroImgen` sin incluir `.jpg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una manera de hacerlo sería así:

1. Identificar el `div`
2. Buscar en él el primer elemento `img`
3. Obtener el valor actual de `src` y dividirlo en partes usando `split`
4. Obtener el último valor, mediante el uso de `pop()`
5. Obtener el valor a reemplazar usando `lastIndexOf` y el punto `.`
6. Finalmente, reemplazar el valor antiguo por el nuevo (aquí se cambiará `NumeroImgen` por `nuevonombre`).

```js
var elDiv=document.getElementById('imgUser');
var elImg=elDiv.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
var src=elImg.src;
var srcParts=src.split('/');
var lastPart = srcParts.pop() || srcParts.pop();  // maneja un potencial / al final de la URL
var toReplace = lastPart.substring(0, lastPart.lastIndexOf('.'));
var newSrc=src.replace(toReplace, 'nuevonombre');
console.log(newSrc);
```

```html
<div id="div_Ejem" class="ve">
  <div style="width: 30px; height: 30px; z-index : 150; position: absolute; "><img src="icon.Gif" width="30" height="30" title="Assistance" alt="" style="cursor: pointer; "> </div>
  <div id="imgUser"><img id="img_9905" src="/folder1/folder2/NumeroImgen.jpg/" /></div><span class="dataUser">INACTIVE <br /></span></div>
```